# Two images side by side in rmarkdown using knitr?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

In Rmarkdown I want to print two images from the web side by side. I'm trying this

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="33%", fig.align = "center", fig.cap="Examples of the FPTP bias: In Prairies (left) and Greater Toronto area (right). Source: www.fairvote.ca"}

knitr::include_graphics(
  c("https://www.fairvote.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Western-alienation-website-FPTP-page.png", "https://www.fairvote.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Toronto-Peel-halton-2019-results-website-FPTP.jpg")
  )

```
````

But instead I'm getting this - they are still printed one on top of the other:

[image]

Please advise. Note: I dont what to use `cowplot` or any other package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include the argument `fig.show='hold'`.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="33%", fig.align = "center", fig.show='hold', fig.cap="Examples of the FPTP bias: In Prairies (left) and Greater Toronto area (right). Source: www.fairvote.ca"}
knitr::include_graphics(
  c("https://www.fairvote.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Western-alienation-website-FPTP-page.png",
    "https://www.fairvote.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Toronto-Peel-halton-2019-results-website-FPTP.jpg")
)
```
````

Here is what it looks like now:
[image: Here is what it looks like now.]

Comment: Thanks! Just for the record, this topic was also covered in the R Markdown Cookbook: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figures-side.html

Comment: Awesome! Thanks alot. Is there a way to insert characters in between the images:  like `knitr::include_graphics( "a) ",
  c("https://www.fairvote.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Western-alienation-website-FPTP-page.png", "b)"
    "https://www.fairvote.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Toronto-Peel-halton-2019-results-website-FPTP.jpg") )` - so we can refer to images as "See Figure 1.b" ?

Comment: @IVIM not sure about this one, I haven't done this. Maybe you could open a new question!